# Mongoose overwrite the document rather that `$set` fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say, i have a document:

```
{
  _id: 'some_mongodb_id',
  name: 'john doe',
  phone: '+12345678901',
}
```

I want to update this document:

```
.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 'some_mongodb_id'}, {name: 'Dan smith'})
```

And the result should be this:

```
{
  _id: 'some_mongodb_id',
  name: 'Dan smith',
}
```

The property, that is not specified, should be removed.

How do i do that?

Comment: Did you try to use the update function (instead of findOneAndUpdate)?

Comment: @israel.zinc i have, no difference

Comment: @israel.zinc And it would not make a difference. It's "mongoose" that is doing this by adding [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) into the "update object" where the standard driver would just pass that object through "as is". So this behavior needs to be "turned off" for mongoose, in order to make it work just like you are actually asking it to.

Answer (score 29):

Actually, but for the fact that mongoose is actually "messing with" the update under the covers, this is actually the default action of your submission to a regular MongoDB function.

So mongoose deems it "wise" as a convenience method to "presume" you meant to issue a [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) instruction here. Since you actually do not want to do that in this case, you turn off that behavior via `{ overwrite: true }` in the options passed to any `.update()` method:

As a full example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const testSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  phone: String
});

const Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    // Clean data
    await Promise.all(
      Object.keys(conn.models).map( m => conn.models[m].remove({}) )
    );

    // Create a document
    let test = await Test.create({
      name: 'john doe',
      phone: '+12345678901'
    });
    log(test);

    // This update will apply using $set for the name
    let notover = await Test.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: test._id },
      { name: 'Bill S. Preston' },
      { new: true }
    );
    log(notover);

    // This update will just use the supplied object, and overwrite
    let updated = await Test.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: test._id },
      { name: 'Dan Smith' },
      { new: true, overwrite: true }
    );
    log(updated);


  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})()
```

Produces:

```
Mongoose: tests.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: tests.insert({ name: 'john doe', phone: '+12345678901', _id: ObjectId("596efb0ec941ff0ec319ac1e"), __v: 0 })
{
  "__v": 0,
  "name": "john doe",
  "phone": "+12345678901",
  "_id": "596efb0ec941ff0ec319ac1e"
}
Mongoose: tests.findAndModify({ _id: ObjectId("596efb0ec941ff0ec319ac1e") }, [], { '$set': { name: 'Bill S. Preston' } }, { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false, fields: {} })
{
  "_id": "596efb0ec941ff0ec319ac1e",
  "name": "Bill S. Preston",
  "phone": "+12345678901",
  "__v": 0
}
Mongoose: tests.findAndModify({ _id: ObjectId("596efb0ec941ff0ec319ac1e") }, [], { name: 'Dan Smith' }, { new: true, overwrite: true, upsert: false, remove: false, fields: {} })
{
  "_id": "596efb0ec941ff0ec319ac1e",
  "name": "Dan Smith"
}
```

Showing the document is "overwritten" because we suppressed the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operation that otherwise would have been interpolated. The two samples show first without the `overwrite` option, which applies the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) modifier, and then "with" the `overwrite` option, where the object you passed in for the "update" is respected and no such [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) modifier is applied.

Note, this is how the MongoDB Node driver does this "by default". So the behavior of adding in the "implicit" [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) is being done by mongoose, unless you tell it not to.

---

> **NOTE** The true way to "replace" would actually be to use `replaceOne`, either as the API method of [`replaceOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.replaceOne) or through [`bulkWrite()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite). The `overwrite` is a legacy of how mongoose wants to apply `$set` as described and demonstrated above, however the MongoDB official API introduces `replaceOne` as a *"special"* king of `update()` operation which ***does not allow*** the usage of atomic operators like `$set` within the statement and will error if you try.
>
> This is much clearer semantically since **replace** reads very clearly as to what the method is actually used for. Within standard API calls to the `update()` variants of course still allow you to omit the atomic operators and will just *replace* content anyway. But warnings should be expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this overwrite feature is totally undocumented :-(

Comment: I got this error:
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ upsert: true; overwrite: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFindOneAndUpdateOptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'overwrite' does not exist in type 'QueryFindOneAndUpdateOptions'.ts(2769)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `upsert` option, and it will replace document:

```
var collection = db.collection('test');
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  {'_id': 'some_mongodb_id'},
  {name: 'Dan smith Only'},
  {upsert: true},
  function (err, doc) {
    console.log(doc);
  }
);
```

But the problem here - is that `doc` in callback is found document but not updated.
Hence you need perform something like this:

```
var collection = db.collection('test');
collection.update(
  {'_id': 'some_mongodb_id'},
  {name: 'Dan smith Only'},
  {upsert: true},
  function (err, doc) {
    collection.findOne({'_id': 'some_mongodb_id'}, function (err, doc) {
        console.log(doc);
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: You can use the option {new:true} to return the updated Document.

Answer (score 0):

### Since the `.update()` method is deprecated.

A more explicit method for the above problem is to use `.replaceOne()` method.

And `{overwrite : true}` property is NOT required in `replaceOne()` method here.

So if we **pass only `newContent`** as the second parameter of `replaceOne()` then the article content will appear with **NO title** (NOT even the old title) because we are replacing the whole old document with new one having `NO title`.

```js
.post("/article/update", function(req, res){
    Article.replaceOne(
        {title : req.body.oldArticle},   // filter
        {title : req.body.newTitle, content : req.body.newContent},
    )
    .then(function(){
        res.send("Successfully Updated the article");
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.send("Unable to Update the article");
    });
});
```

##### If you find anything wrong then please give your valuable suggestions. It'll help me to improve

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the replaceOne is also a very good option if you do not want the phone value to show, try this
.replaceOne({_id: 'some_mongodb_id'}, {name: 'Dan smith'})