# Update Document including empty fields via Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm sending the following object for mongoose to update:

```
{
  "name" : "John",
  "fruit" : "5a3d678d9b1549979d81c6ba" // this is an objectID
}
```

and the method:

```
db_user.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body).then(function(user, err) {
  res.send(user);
});
```

This works fine if I replace the fruit with another fruitID which is what I'm trying to update.

However, if I send an object with no fruit, it won't remove the fruit field from the user document. Such as:

```
{
  "name" : "John"
}
```

It will update whatever name I pass, but it won't remove the fruit field. Why?

Also: I can't be checking for each field that I'm sending or not and do an `$unset` for each accordingly, because I'm sending a lot of fields. I just want Mongoose to override the old document with the new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose overwrite the document rather that \`$set\` fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182011/mongoose-overwrite-the-document-rather-that-set-fields)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little complicated / ugly and I'm sure there is an easier way but this should work if you want to update on specific thing and not have it fill the other values in blank.

```
function updateItem(req, res) {

  function GetObjectFromKeyValuePairs(pairs) {
    var tmp = {};

    for(var key in pairs)
      if(key[0] !== "_")
        if(pairs[key].length !== 0)
          tmp[`${key}`] = `${pairs[key]}`;
    return tmp;
  }
  let updateOnlyChangedVals = GetObjectFromKeyValuePairs(req.body);

  DB.Item.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: updateOnlyChangedVals},{new:true}, (err, uItem) => {
    if (err) { return console.log("index error: " + err); }
    res.json(uItem);
  });
}
```